# Jboss as7 ejb injection inside cdi beans

Tags: jboss, glassfish, ejb, cdi, weld

I have developed an ear application using ejb3.1, jsf2.0 and cdi enabled.

I have packaged my application as ear with ejb modules defining the session beans, ejbremote jar defining the remote session interfaces and the jpa entities, and the war application which includes dependency on ejbremote jar (for the remote interface lookup, and the jpa entities).

Scenario:

If i inject directly session beans defined in the ejb jar in any cdi bean, jboss fails to find  the righ proxy to inject, and `throws a ClassCastException EjbManagerRemote field of my cdi bean cannot be cast to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78`

However, with glassfish, this scenario works perfectly.

To circumvent the jboss problem, i have developed a session bean inside the war (something like a producer: actually intend to do this) file where i inject the session beans and then inject this local session bean into the cdi beans which give me the reference to the session beans.

My question is, why does jboss fail to inject the remote session beans, yet glassfish has no problem?

What am i missing in ejb and cdi bean injection?

Note: am injecting the beans using @EJB annotation.

Thanks

Comment: do you have any jboss-deployment-structure.xml or manifest entries for dependencies defined? can you post those? can you also post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Which version of AS7? Sounds like a bug. May be fixed in a newer version.

Comment: +1 for @JohnAment, without concrete trace and code this is a chrystal ball topic, since CDI in combination with modular classloading can get ugly ...